# How to get different colors for reversible arrows in chemfig?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I have the following reaction scheme in chemfig:

[image]

***I need for some of the reversible reactions: forward reactions arrow in black and the backward reactions arrow in red. Is it possible in chemfig?***

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]}[,,,red] Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30,,,red] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30,,,red] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30,,,red] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}[,,,red]
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]}[,,,red] U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As requested in the comments, here is a possible solution, that does not overwrite the definition of `<=>`, but rather defines its own new arrow `<=r>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow3{<=r>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#3}%
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u0){}%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d0){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u1){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d1){};%
    \begingroup
        \pgfarrowharpoontrue
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode u0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode u1);%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle,red](\CF_arrowstartnode d1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode d0);%
    \endgroup
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0.5}+\CF_arrowstartnode{#2}{0.5}-\CF_arrowendnode%
}
\catcode`\_=8

\begin{document}

\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=r>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]}[,,,] Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30,,,] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30,,,] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30,,,] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}[,,,]
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]}[,,,] U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

The following code applies the color change to all `<=>` arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow3{<=>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#3}%
    \path[allow upside down](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u0){}%
            node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d0){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode u1){}%
            node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=-1pt](\CF_arrowstartnode d1){};%
    \begingroup
        \pgfarrowharpoontrue
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode u0)--(\CF_arrowstartnode u1);%
        \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle,red](\CF_arrowstartnode d1)--(\CF_arrowstartnode d0);% <---------------modified line
    \endgroup
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0.5}+\CF_arrowstartnode{#2}{0.5}-\CF_arrowendnode%
}
\catcode`\_=8

\begin{document}

\schemestart
P \arrow(P--Q){<=>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]}[,,,] Q
\arrow{<=>[$\mathrm{k_{qs}}$]}[30,,,] S \arrow(S--T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{st}}$]}[-30,,,] T
\arrow(@Q--R){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{qr}}$]}[-30,,,] R
\arrow(@R--@T){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{rt}}$]}[,,,]
\arrow(@T--U){<=>[][$\mathrm{k_{tu}}$]}[,,,] U
\arrow(@U--V){->[$\mathrm{k_{uv}}$]} V
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

I have copied the definition of `<=>` from `chemfig.tex` and added `,red` in the marked line in the code.

This results in the following output:

[image]

---

A previous version of these MWEs which work with older versions of the `chemfig` package (prior to v 1.4) can be accessed through the revision history of this post.

Comment: I had to modify the question. I need it for only some reactions; not all reactions.

Comment: @nxkryptor: I have updated my answer according to your request.

Comment: The color changes, however the harpoon arrows are missing and I get the following error:

! Undefined control sequence.
\<=r> ... @d1){};\begingroup \pgfarrowharpoontrue 
                                                  \expandafter \draw \expand...
l.24 P \arrow(P--Q){<=r>[$\mathrm{k_{pq}}$]}[,,,]

Comment: @nxkryptor: I have tried to reproduce the error you described by using the above MWE, but unfortunately I was not able to. Did you make sure, there are no typos in the code?

Comment: I check for typos; everything looks fine. The interesting thing is if I comment \pgfarrowharpoontrue, the error no longer exists. However, the harpoon arrows are missing.

Comment: I am compiling it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, just for information. I don't think it matters. I have checked for every possible source of error. I just can't figure out what is wrong. It just doesn't display the harpoon ends and gives 'Undefined control sequence.'.

Comment: Do you encounter the error while compiling the MWE or with your actual document? I have again made some tests and, at least on my system, the MWE works fine with `latex`, `pdflatex` and `xelatex`, as well as with versions `1.2d` and `1.2e` of `chemfig`.

Comment: The first MWE of your answer.