# Coloring only one side of the two sided arrow of mhchem

Tags: color, arrows, mhchem

For showing a reversible reaction with **mhchem** package one uses `\ce{<=>}`. Now if I want to color one of the two sides by a different color (so not both directions of this two-sided arrow having same color), then what should I do?

Comment: please, be so kind and show us what you have tried so far ...

Comment: @Zarko Using \textcolor{color}{\ce{<=>}} will make both directions same color. If I don't want to use mhchem, then I can use xymatrix package. But I prefer to keep using mhchem package for chemical reactions.

Comment: well, apparently you not like to provide a mwe. than i can't help you further. i'm not wiling (now) to prepare an example from scratch. sorry.

Comment: similar question concerning the `chemfig` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405641/134144